# How to pass a null value as bind parameter

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I have this table `Line` with a DEL_IND column. The possible values are `Y` or `null`

Im using OBIP, and there is a parameter requirement that allows selection of null or Y. 
OBIP do not allow blank in their 'fixed value' menu.

I've tried to enter 'List of Values' in OBIP for No to be `''` (empty string), but it doesnt seem to work.

`LINE.DEL_IND = :P_DELETION_FLAG` << i need to pass the value null for this clause

How do I pass null value selection into the query?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you find the way to pass `NULL`, this:

```
WHERE LINE.DEL_IND = :P_DELETION_FLAG
```

won't work properly. If `:P_DELETION_FLAG` is NULL, query should look like this:

```
WHERE (LINE.DEL_IND = :P_DELETION_FLAG or :P_DELETION_FLAG IS NULL)
```

because

```
WHERE LINE.DEL_IND = NULL
```

is invalid; should be

```
WHERE LINE.DEL_IND IS NULL (or IS NOT NULL)
```